# Runtime error in insertion sort

Tags: c++, runtime-error, insertion-sort

Im trying to do insertion sort using linked list but this code seems to have runtime error.

```
void Insert(int data)
{

    node* temp=new node();
    temp->data=data;
    temp->link=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        return;
    }
    node* current=head;
    if(current->data>data)
    {
        temp->link=head;
        head=temp;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        current=head;
        node* trail=head;
        while(current->data<=data)
        {
            trail=current;
            current=current->link;
        }
        trail->link=temp;
        temp->link=current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the else block of your second if.

You're looping through the list, and everything seems fine...but what happens if  you get to the end of the list and `current->data` is still less than or equal to `data`?? Uh oh! `current = current->link`, current will now be `NULL`, so the next `current->data` will be trying to dereference a null pointer!

Just add a check for that in your loop condition and everything will be peachy:

```
while(current && current->data <= data) {
```

This expression will now short circuit if `current` is the null pointer, saving you from that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only error but:

```
    current=head;
    node* trail=head;
    while(current->data<=data) // <-- This doesn't check if current->link is NULL
    {
        trail=current;
        current=current->link; /// <-- If current is NULL this would explode
    }
    trail->link=temp;
    temp->link=current;
```